# error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit

Tags: scala, syntax-error, apache-spark

I am relatively new to Spark and scala programming.

I was trying to execute the simple pagerank algorithm using scala. But I encountered this error when compiling.

```
error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit
```

I have attached the code I am using.

```
val output = ranks.collect()
output.foreach(tup => println(tup._1 + " has page rank: " + tup._2)).saveAsTextFile("/user/ssimhadr/ScalaWordCount_Output")
```

Comment: this is an issue with the structure of your program, probably related with a function containing this expression - the code provided is insufficient to say where the problem is.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `foreach` is purely for side-effecting (which is what you're doing with `println`).

Answer (score 1):

foreach is, as Ryan pointed out, solely for side-effects. It returns Unit and not the List itself. Ergo no chaining.

Now what you are actually doing is the following:

```
val output = ranks.collect()
val realoutput: Unit = output.foreach(tup => println(tup._1 + " has page rank: " + tup._2))
realoutput.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

`saveAsTextFile` is not a member of `Unit` and you get your error message

You should be doing:

```
ranks.foreach(tup => println(tup._1 + " has page rank: " + tup._2))
ranks.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

or

```
ranks.saveAsTextFile(...)
ranks.collect().foreach(tup => println(tup._1 + " has page rank: " + tup._2))
```

Comment: `ranks.collect` will return an array of values, which does not have a `saveAsTextFile` method. Using collect in this case is unnecessary.

Comment: correct, totally overlooked this. will update the post accordingly